# A full LinkedIn profile for testing an app

Tags: linkedin-api

I was wondering if there is a full profile on LinkedIn that I can test my app on. By full I mean a profile which has all the fields and can be accessed publicly (using the LinkedIn API).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't know of any publicly accessible test profile and I would be suprised if there was.

Section II A. of the [LinkedIn API TOS](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use) have this to say about test accounts:

> For testing purposes only, you may create up to five LinkedIn accounts. Accounts must be created manually and not via any automated means, including scripts. These test accounts must not interact with non-test accounts (e.g. they must not be used to post messages in Groups), or be used to circumvent user limits. These accounts must have profiles that clearly identify them as test accounts, not have any profile positions at real companies besides your own, and be listed as Developers on your Developer Account.

You might also find [this discussion](http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/test-accounts) helpful.

Comment: Thanks. It's bee so long I've forgotten about this question. I ended up creating an account as said above.

Comment: Linkedin is so riduculously bad.

Comment: You'll need a spare phone number though, as of today when I try to register a new test accounts it asks for a phone verification to create it, and you can't use a phone already registered.

Comment: I just created a test account without a phone number, FWIW. I'm not exactly sure if things have changed - but the only time I was even asked for one was when they were trying to send me a link to download the app but I just clicked "next" instead of giving it to them.

Answer (score 5):

Linkedin's staff said in [this thread](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/test-accounts) that the only way to test their APIs is by manually creating your own test accounts.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: The link is no longer available. It is redirecting to https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin