# Are there fictional test users for LinkedIn or Facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

Do either LinkedIn or Facebook provide a fictional user ID that can be used for testing an app that calls their APIs?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook provides [test users for app developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users):

> ### Test Users for Apps
>
> A test user is a special Facebook account, invisible to real accounts,
>   which can be created within an app for the purpose of manual or
>   automated testing of that app's Facebook integration.
>
> We ensure that test users are exempt from our spam and fake account
>   detection systems so that you can test your app without worrying about
>   getting disabled.
>
> You can create, access and delete test user accounts in a couple of
>   ways - by using the Graph API to do it programmatically, or by using
>   the App Dashboard to do it manually.

As for LinkedIn, this SO question may be useful: [A full LinkedIn profile for testing an app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12596369/404623)